# Ubuntu android studio installation error

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-studio

I am using 64 bit operating system(ubuntu 15.04) and I am also new in linux platform.

When I try to install  android studio I got an error "Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool".

I try this one and it does not work:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

Can u help me?

Comment: aren't you using the LTS version?
if you aren't then you should use the LTS Version.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to install lib32stdc++6. Try the following command:

- sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6

Answer (score 0):

Use this

`sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6`

For Ubuntu **15.04**,15.10,16.04 LTS & Debian 8